# Check if username/email available method

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, registration

I try to make a secure method that checks if a username or email is not taken and I'm not sure if this is the right way. How can I do this better?

```
private function checkAvailability() {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email");
            $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $st->bindValue(":username", $_POST["username"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindValue(":email", $_POST["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->execute();
            if($st->fetchColumn() > 0) {
                $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username");
                $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $st->bindValue(":username", $_POST["username"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $st->execute();
                if($st->fetchColumn() > 0) {
                    throw new Exception("That username is already taken");
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("That e-mail is already registered.")
                }
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
            $conn = null;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Database error: " . $e->geMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Registration failed: " . $e->geMessage();
        }
    }

    public function registerUser() {
        if(self::checkAvailability) {
            // register user
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you fetching data from the database twice?  Just check once and if there's a record show one message: "That username or email address is not available."  I'd also suggest not using exceptions to indicate this message, since this a normal non-exceptional logical condition of the system.  Returning some kind of status from the function would be better.

Comment: "Something" is better than "Nothing". You do your best. This is not a stupid question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already on the right path here.

The query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email` can be a performance problem, because the db can't use any index here. So you might want to split that in two statements one for username and one for email. That would also help you determining which error occured.

Also you don't need every hit in the db just the first, so a `limit 1` is also usefull.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd just like to point out that MySQL *can* use indexes with that query. If both `email` and `username` are indexed `VARCHAR` then query should be using index_merge with union. See `EXPLAIN` and MySQL reference manual. Splitting the query into two parts may make things faster and will definitely make it easier to determine which error occurred.